# Exception getting raised when bs4 module is used to parse the output

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse a certain text in a webpage using bs4 module. The file gets downloaded using requests module but when i am trying to run the bs4 module against the contents but its throws the exception ' error downloading page'. The status_code for the downloaded file is 200. Not sure what i am missing here. I have installed lxml module to avoid the warning thrown by bs4 module.

```
try:
    import requests, bs4
    import os
    import ntpath as path
    import lxml
    res = requests.get('http://nostarch.com/',stream=True)
    print(res.status_code, len(res.text))
    if res.status_code == 200:
        bs = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
        out = bs.select('p')
        print('the no of elements matched :', len(out))
        for i in range(len(out)):
            print(i,'th Text is :-', out[i].getText())

except Exception as err:
    print('error downloading page', res.raise_for_status())
```

OUTPUT:-

200 51431

error downloading page None

Comment: a) Fix your indentation, b) change `out1` to `out`, ie: `out=bs.select('p')`

Comment: done. Still no go.

Comment: You try-except block is too big and not printig useful info. If you change `res.raise_for_status()` to `err.message` you 'll see that `out` is not defined. If you change `out1=bs.select('p')` to `out=bs.select('p')` you should get results.

Comment: out1 to out is taken care . I changed the res.raise_for_status() to err and now getting following error. 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 22094: character maps to <undefined>'

Comment: That's an encoding error. Change `res.text` to `res.content`

Comment: thank you so much. it worked after taking care of the encoding.